# javax.servlet.ServletException with HTTP Status 500 is thrown

Tags: java, spring

type Exception report

message org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    ICmGroupCustContractSV cannot be resolved to a type
    ICmGroupCustContractSV cannot be resolved to a type
    ICmGroupCustContractSV cannot be resolved to a type

```
com.ai.appframe2.web.filter.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:492)
```

root cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    ICmGroupCustContractSV cannot be resolved to a type
    ICmGroupCustContractSV cannot be resolved to a type
    ICmGroupCustContractSV cannot be resolved to a type

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:412)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
com.asiainfo.crm.manage.ord.common.audit.web.UrlSecurityFilter.doFilter(UrlSecurityFilter.java:181)
com.ai.appframe2.web.filter.expire.ExpireResponseHeaderFilter.doFilter(ExpireResponseHeaderFilter.java:130)
com.ai.appframe2.web.filter.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:420)
```

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    ICmGroupCustContractSV cannot be resolved to a type
    ICmGroupCustContractSV cannot be resolved to a type
    ICmGroupCustContractSV cannot be resolved to a type

```
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:865)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:794)
org.apache.jsp.crm.so.bboss.CustInfo_jsp._jspService(CustInfo_jsp.java:2448)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
com.asiainfo.crm.manage.ord.common.audit.web.UrlSecurityFilter.doFilter(UrlSecurityFilter.java:181)
com.ai.appframe2.web.filter.expire.ExpireResponseHeaderFilter.doFilter(ExpireResponseHeaderFilter.java:130)
com.ai.appframe2.web.filter.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:420)
```

root cause

java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    ICmGroupCustContractSV cannot be resolved to a type
    ICmGroupCustContractSV cannot be resolved to a type
    ICmGroupCustContractSV cannot be resolved to a type

```
com.asiainfo.crm.center.customer.rule.CmPrivBusiRule.initSessionEntityPriv(CmPrivBusiRule.java:1382)
com.asiainfo.crm.center.customer.rule.CmPrivBusiRule.checkManagerInfo(CmPrivBusiRule.java:1485)
org.apache.jsp.crm.so.bboss.CustInfo_jsp._jspService(CustInfo_jsp.java:451)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
com.asiainfo.crm.manage.ord.common.audit.web.UrlSecurityFilter.doFilter(UrlSecurityFilter.java:181)
com.ai.appframe2.web.filter.expire.ExpireResponseHeaderFilter.doFilter(ExpireResponseHeaderFilter.java:130)
com.ai.appframe2.web.filter.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:420)
```

What happen :(((

Comment: Can you check your work space for Compilation Errors?

Comment: It seems that xxx.java file didn't build but eclipse didn't show the reason.